# Is sparse tensor multiplication implemented in TensorFlow?

Tags: sparse-matrix, tensorflow

Multiplication of sparse tensors with themselves or with dense tensors does not seem to work in TensorFlow.  The following example

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([[1.0,2.0],
                 [3.0,4.0]])
y = tf.SparseTensor(indices=[[0,0],[1,1]], values=[1.0,1.0], shape=[2,2])
z = tf.matmul(x,y)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
print(sess.run([x, y, z]))
```

fails with the error message

```py
TypeError: Input 'b' of 'MatMul' Op has type string that does not match type 
float32 of argument 'a'
```

Both tensors have values of type float32 as seen by evaluating them  without the multiplication op.  Multiplication of y with itself returns a similar error message.  Multipication of x with itself works fine.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

General-purpose multiplication for `tf.SparseTensor` is not currently implemented in TensorFlow. However, there are three partial solutions, and the right one to choose will depend on the characteristics of your data:

- If you have a `tf.SparseTensor` and a `tf.Tensor`, you can use [`tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/sparse_ops/math_operations#sparse_tensor_dense_matmul) to multiply them. This is more efficient than the next approach if one of the tensors is too large to fit in memory when densified: the documentation has more guidance about how to decide between these two methods. Note that it accepts a `tf.SparseTensor` as the **first** argument, so to solve your exact problem you will need to use the `adjoint_a` and `adjoint_b` arguments, and transpose the result.
- If you have two sparse tensors and need to multiply them, the simplest (if not the most performant) way is to convert them to dense and use `tf.matmul`:

  ```
  a = tf.SparseTensor(...)
  b = tf.SparseTensor(...)

  c = tf.matmul(tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(a, 0.0),
                tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(b, 0.0),
                a_is_sparse=True, b_is_sparse=True)
  ```

  Note that the optional `a_is_sparse` and `b_is_sparse` arguments mean that "`a` (or `b`) has a dense representation but a large number of its entries are zero", which triggers the use of a different multiplication algorithm.
- For the special case of sparse *vector* by (potentially large and sharded) dense matrix multiplication, and the values in the vector are 0 or 1, the [`tf.nn.embedding_lookup`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/nn/embeddings#embedding_lookup) operator may be more appropriate. [This tutorial](http://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/word2vec/index.html#building_the_graph) discusses when you might use embeddings and how to invoke the operator in more detail.
- For the special case of sparse *matrix* by (potentially large and sharded) dense matrix, [`tf.nn.embedding_lookup_sparse()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/nn/embeddings#embedding_lookup_sparse) may be appropriate. This function accepts one or two `tf.SparseTensor` objects, with `sp_ids` representing the non-zero values, and the optional `sp_weights` representing their values (which otherwise default to one).

Comment: Why `tf.sparse_matmul` is not covered? How is it different?

Comment: How to make element-wise multiplication of two sparse tensor?

Answer (score 12):

Recently, `tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul(...)` was added that allows multiplying a sparse matrix by a dense matrix.

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/sparse_ops.html#sparse_tensor_dense_matmul

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1241

Comment: Note: This has a limitation of having a rank of 2 (both the matrices). This does not work if the matrices have a rank > 2

Answer (score 5):

In TF2.4.1 you can use the methods in `tensorflow.python.ops.linalg.sparse.sparse_csr_matrix_ops` to multiply to arbitrary `SparseTensor` (I think up to 3 dimensions).

Something like the following should be used (in general you turn the sparse tensors into a CSR representation)

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.ops.linalg.sparse import sparse_csr_matrix_ops


def tf_multiply(a: tf.SparseTensor, b: tf.SparseTensor):
    a_sm = sparse_csr_matrix_ops.sparse_tensor_to_csr_sparse_matrix(
        a.indices, a.values, a.dense_shape
    )

    b_sm = sparse_csr_matrix_ops.sparse_tensor_to_csr_sparse_matrix(
        b.indices, b.values, b.dense_shape
    )

    c_sm = sparse_csr_matrix_ops.sparse_matrix_sparse_mat_mul(
        a=a_sm, b=b_sm, type=tf.float32
    )

    c = sparse_csr_matrix_ops.csr_sparse_matrix_to_sparse_tensor(
        c_sm, tf.float32
    )

    return tf.SparseTensor(
        c.indices, c.values, dense_shape=c.dense_shape
    )
```

For a while I was prefering `scipy` multiplication (via a `py_function`) because this multiplication in TF (2.3 and 2.4) was not performing as well as scipy. I tried again recently and, either I changed something on my code, or there was some fix in 2.4.1 that makes the TF sparse multiplication faster that using scipy, in both CPU and GPU.

Comment: Why is there a `self`?

Comment: @LucaCappelletti I was implementing this as a method of a class, but the self is not required for the demonstration here. Thanks.

Comment: works perfectly (tf-2.6)

Comment: Can there also be a version, based on python.ops, that supports sparse-dense multiplication for tensors with rank 3 (with batch dimension) because tf.sparse.sparse_dense_matmul does not support that?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that

```
tf.sparse_matmul(
    a,
    b,
    transpose_a=None,
    transpose_b=None,
    a_is_sparse=None,
    b_is_sparse=None,
    name=None
)
```

is not for multiplication of two `SparseTensors`.

`a` and `b` are `Tensors` not `SparseTensors`. And I have tried that, it is not working with `SparseTensors`.

Answer (score 1):

tf.sparse_matmul is for multiplying two dense tensor not sparse type of data structure. That function is just an optimized version of tensor multiplication if the given matrix (or both two matrixes) have many zero value. Again it does not accept sparse tensor data type. It accepts dense tensor data type. It might fasten your calculations if values are mostly zero.

as far as I know there is no implementation of two sparse type tensor muliplication. but just one sparse one dense which is tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul(x, y) !

Answer (score -2):

To make the answer more complete:

```
tf.sparse_matmul(
    a,
    b,
    transpose_a=None,
    transpose_b=None,
    a_is_sparse=None,
    b_is_sparse=None,
    name=None
)
```

exists as well:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse_matmul

Comment: I get: `TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got <tensorflow.python.framework.ops.SparseTensor object at 0x7f90873f4fd0>`

Comment: pcejrowski ! here is what your llink write "Both "a" and "b" must be Tensors not SparseTensors" . unlike your advice a_is_sparse=True does not mean matrix is sparse type . it just means matrix a has many many zero values, So algorithm calculates it rapidly by using that prior information !!