# matrix multiplication with sparse output specified by another sparse matrix on tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I would like to implement a matrix multiplication on TensorFlow like *C* = *A* · *B* where *A* ∈ ℝ<sup>*n*,*k*</sup> and *B* ∈ ℝ<sup>*k*,*n*</sup>. In my case, *n* could be potentially large but *k* is typically small (e.g. low rank or latent embeddings).

As you know the dense matrix *C* ∈ ℝ<sup>*n*,*n*</sup> is expensive to store in RAM. However, the only entries in *C* I want to retain are sparse. That is, by defining another sparse matrix *D* ∈ ℝ<sup>*n*,*n*</sup>, what I really care about are those values with indices `[i,j]` having values in *D*. The non-empty values in *D* should only be `1`.

So, instead of doing stuff like this:

```
tmp = tf.matmul(A,B)
C = tf.SparseTensor(D.indices, tf.gather_nd(tmp, D.indices)*D.values, D.dense_shape)
```

I want to avoid explicitly computing the dense tensor `tmp` above.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is sparse tensor multiplication implemented in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34030140/is-sparse-tensor-multiplication-implemented-in-tensorflow)

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane to my understand, the matmul of sparse tensor with dense tensor would have a dense output. It is not clear how I can have a sparse tensor as output.

Comment: both _A_ and _B_ are dense matrices in my case.

Comment: What do you want to do with `C` later on? Do you want to compute `tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul(C, x)`?

Comment: @JonasAdler I want to do the following later: `C=tf.nn.tanh(C)`, then `C=tf.sparse_softmax(C)`, then `tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul(sp_a=C, b=x)`

Comment: This operation (dense matmul with sparse output) is not implemented in tensorflow as of august 2017.

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial (not complete because I don't thoroughly understand your goals) answer found here: [Compressed matrix multiplication](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.1320.pdf).

You are probably asking for the problem known as "Matrix Multiplication with Sparse Output".

Read the first section (introduction):

> "Our method can be seen as a compressed sensing method for the matrix product, with the nonstandard idea that the **SKETCH** of AB is computed **WITHOUT EXPLICITLY CONSTRUCTING** AB"

Under some assumptions (sparseness of the output matrix and number of sketches) and using **ERROR CORRECTING CODES** one can obtain the largest entries of the initial product without multiplying A and B.

Look at figure 2 for an example.