# How can I perform Sparse Matrix * Sparse Matrix Multiplication in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix

At present I am trying to calculate matrix multiplication using TensorFlow where both the matrices are in sparse form. I tried with `tf.sparse_matmul()` but in that case I had to convert back to dense form which ruins my project objectives. Please suggest me what can I do in this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is sparse tensor multiplication implemented in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34030140/is-sparse-tensor-multiplication-implemented-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `tf.sparse_matmul`?

```
 sparse_matumul_result = tf.sparse_matmul(a, b)
```

If you need `sparse_matmul_result` as a sparse also, you can do:

```
 tf.contrib.layers.dense_to_sparse(sparse_matmul_result)
```

Comment: According to documentation, Both the matrices must be Tensors but not SparseTensors. But in my case both the matrices are SparseTensors. I am afraid, for using tf.sparse_matmul() I need to convert SparseTensors into dense tensor.