# Dense vector on sparse matrix multiplication in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

What is proper way of dense vector on sparse matrix multiplication in tensorflow?

According to documentation [tf.matmul](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/matmul) support sparse matrix multiplication, so do I need to use [tf.sparse_matmul](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse_matmul)? (And also [tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse_tensor_dense_matmul) exist, so in which cases each of them should be used?)

Also do I need to convert my sparse matrix to [tf.SparseTensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/SparseTensor) ? Also it not obvious what [tf.convert_to_tensor_or_sparse_tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor_or_sparse_tensor) is doing and how to convert dense numpy matrix or scipy sparse matrix for tensorflow suitable input.

Here what I have tried(timing are for CPU):

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

np.random.seed(2018)

# Parameters
n = 10*1000
m = 4*1000
p = 0.1

%%time

# Data preparation
dense_vector = np.random.rand(1,n).astype(np.float32)
print('dense_vector.shape', dense_vector.shape)
#print('dense_vector:')
#print(dense_vector)

dense_matrix = np.random.rand(n*m)
idx = np.random.choice(range(n*m), int((1.0-p)*n*m), replace=False)
dense_matrix[idx] = 0.0
dense_matrix = dense_matrix.reshape(n,m).astype(np.float32)
print('dense_matrix.shape', dense_matrix.shape)
#print('dense_matrix:')
#print(dense_matrix)

dense_vector.shape (1, 10000)
dense_matrix.shape (10000, 4000)
CPU times: user 9.8 s, sys: 2.38 s, total: 12.2 s
Wall time: 12.2 s

%%time

# Dense vector on dense matrix multiplication using numpy

res = dense_vector @ dense_matrix
print('res.shape', res.shape)
#print('res:')
#print(res)

%%time

# Dense vector on dense matrix multiplication using tensorflow tf.matmul V1

dense_vector_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(dense_vector, np.float32)
dense_matrix_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(dense_matrix, np.float32)
res_tf = tf.matmul(dense_vector_tf, dense_matrix_tf)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    res = sess.run(res_tf)
    print('res.shape', res.shape)
    #print('res:')
    #print(res)

res.shape (1, 4000)
CPU times: user 1.88 s, sys: 1.82 s, total: 3.7 s
Wall time: 3.54 s

%%time

# Dense vector on dense matrix multiplication using tensorflow tf.matmul V2

dense_vector_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(dense_vector, np.float32)
dense_matrix_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(dense_matrix, np.float32)
res_tf = tf.matmul(dense_vector_tf, dense_matrix_tf,
                   a_is_sparse=False,
                   b_is_sparse=True)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    res = sess.run(res_tf)
    print('res.shape', res.shape)
    #print('res:')
    #print(res)

res.shape (1, 4000)
CPU times: user 4.91 s, sys: 4.28 s, total: 9.19 s
Wall time: 9.07 s

%%time

# Dense vector on sparse matrix multiplication using tensorflow tf.sparse_matmul V1

dense_vector_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(dense_vector, np.float32)
dense_matrix_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(dense_matrix, np.float32)
res_tf = tf.sparse_matmul(dense_vector_tf, dense_matrix_tf,
                         a_is_sparse=False,
                         b_is_sparse=True)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    res = sess.run(res_tf)
    print('res.shape', res.shape)
    #print('res:')
    #print(res)

res.shape (1, 4000)
CPU times: user 4.82 s, sys: 4.18 s, total: 8.99 s
Wall time: 9 s

%%time

# Dense vector on sparse matrix multiplication using tensorflow tf.sparse_matmul V2

dense_vector_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(dense_vector, np.float32)
dense_matrix_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor_or_sparse_tensor(dense_matrix, np.float32)
res_tf = tf.sparse_matmul(dense_vector_tf, dense_matrix_tf,
                         a_is_sparse=False,
                         b_is_sparse=True)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    res = sess.run(res_tf)
    print('res.shape', res.shape)
    #print('res:')
    #print(res)

res.shape (1, 4000)
CPU times: user 5.07 s, sys: 4.53 s, total: 9.6 s
Wall time: 9.61 s
```

Also I can't see any improvement using sparse matrices, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform efficient sparse matrix multiplication by using tf.matmul?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44859321/how-to-perform-efficient-sparse-matrix-multiplication-by-using-tf-matmul)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is sparse tensor multiplication implemented in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34030140/is-sparse-tensor-multiplication-implemented-in-tensorflow)

Comment: @AllenLavoie Thanks, but this answer don't cover `tf.sparse_matmul` and my question is about more specific case of dense vector on sparse matrix multiplication, so it's not direct duplicate.